# Notification if something is true?

Tags: java, android, events, notifications

I want to create notification. Idea should look like this:

```
if(something == true) {
start notification("something happened!")
};
```

Event is basically same as notification, if I am correct :). Is it possible and how exactly? I am quite new to java.

Comment: use Actions (ActionListener, ItemListener...etc)

Comment: Can you provide small example please?

Answer (score 0):

A click on a button is an event that can be captured by an OnClickListerner

e.g.

```java
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: But is it possible without button? Because I need to get notification after one thing is true to notify person what has happened, not i get notification when event into mobile when i press button.

Comment: as @Dommel suggests, you can use a toast to notify that the event happened, as follows: `if(event_happened==true) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event Happened!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }`

Comment: But I want notification to be for long time, like till it is clicked not short or little bit longer time...

Comment: Maybe too late but instead of a toast, you can also use an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Observer Pattern.